# What is the difference between yoyo and repeat in framer-motion

Tags: framer-motion

I found out that yoyo and repeat are quite identical in framer-motion. I can't find any documentation on yoyo. Only repeat is documented.

```
transition:{{yoyo:3}}
transition:{{repeat:3}}
```

Basically they do animation loop. I only notice the animation loop is slightly different in other details that I can't name.

Can anyone show me the link to yoyo documentation or give me some ideas of their difference or similarity?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think `yoyo` is now called `reverse`, and `reverse` is a type of `repeatType`

`repeatType` can be `loop` (default), `mirror` or `reverse` (`yoyo` previously). So:

```
{
  repeatType: 'loop' | 'mirror' | 'reverse'
}
```

See [that example on Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions68279463-3crvk?file=/src/Example.jsx), tweak `repeatType` to see the difference

Answer (score 0):

as per my console:

> yoyo, loop and flip have been removed from the API. Replace with repeat and repeatType options

yoyo/repeat were interchangeable for a time. Both would accept number of repetitions, as well as, `Infinity`.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the same effect as

```js
transition:{
  yoyo:3
}
```

you will need to write:

```js
transition: {
  repeatType: "mirror",
  repeat: 5,
}
```